# Sendmail in DOCKERized PHP-Application doesn't work

Tags: php, apache, email, docker, sendmail

When trying to send an email with PHP

```
function sendmailoversmtp($name, $mail, $message, $topic)
```

It does not work. The following error is logged:

```
sh: 1: -t: not found
```

`-t -i` is configured as `sendmail_path` in my php.ini. Why is it not found?

My Dockerfile is based on `FROM php:7.0-apache`

Comment: Can you add the body of the sendmailoversmtp function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Command line `sendmail` won't work in a container without some extended setup. The `sendmail` binary normally drops a file into a mailqueue directory for a mail server process to pick up and then send. This would require mounting some mail servers queue directories into a container or trying to run a sendmail process along with your container services. Both are not very "Dockery".

#### sSMTP

[sSMTP](https://wiki.debian.org/sSMTP) is a simple MTA to deliver mail from a computer to a mail hub (SMTP server)

Install `ssmtp` in the container and configure `/etc/ssmtp/ssmtp.conf` to send email via a real smtp server.

You could run a [mail server in another container](https://github.com/catatnight/docker-postfix), use an existing service, or use an [external mail host](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSMTP#Forward_to_a_Gmail_mail_server). There would generally be a mail server running on the Docker host itself, but it may not always be addressable from the container or accessible in the same way across different hosts.

Then configure PHP to use `ssmtp`

```
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/ssmtp -t
```

Comment: where do you put your php.ini ?

Comment: @jujule That's entirely dependent on the build of PHP you are using. Probably best to find your existing one and edit that